# PowerShell Rest API

Tags: powershell

I am running the below script to extract values using a REST API call. I am getting the below output.

Is it possible to remove @{Avail Bytes=} from the output. I only need the actual value in the output.

Thanks

[image]

```
# Accept input parameters
Param([String]$isilonip,[String]$username,[String]$password)


# With a default cert you would normally see a cert error (code from blogs.msdn.com)
add-type @"
using System.Net;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
 
    public class TrustAll : ICertificatePolicy {
    public TrustAll() {}
    public bool CheckValidationResult(
        ServicePoint sPoint, X509Certificate cert,
        WebRequest req, int problem) {
        return true;
    }
}
"@
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::CertificatePolicy = new-object TrustAll

#if the correct parameters were not passed we exit after a message
if (!($isilonip -and $username -and $password )) {
   write "failed to specify parameters";
   write "Example: .\ps_isilon_get_quotas_via_papi.ps1 -isilonip 192.168.1.2 -username root -password p@ssw0rd1" ;
   exit
}
  
# Encode basic authorization header and create baseurl
$EncodedAuthorization = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($username + ':' + $password)
$EncodedPassword = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($EncodedAuthorization)
$headers = @{"Authorization"="Basic $($EncodedPassword)"}
$baseurl = 'https://' + $isilonip +":8080"
 

$resourceurl = "/platform/5/storagepool/nodepools"

$uri = $baseurl + $resourceurl
$ISIObject = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Headers $headers -Method Get 

$Avail_Bytes = $ISIObject.nodepools |  select-object -Property @{Name="Avail Bytes";E={($_.usage.avail_bytes)}}

write-host "\nMessage: Avail Bytes";
write-host "\nStatistics:$Avail_Bytes";
```

Comment: $Avail_Bytes contains an object and you force a string output. the best probably is to remove those write-hosts (last 2 lines) and replace it with ```return $Avail_Bytes``` this will return the object as it is - which is much better as a string for further processing

Comment: For further processing, I need to read only the actual value. Need a way to remove the object name from the output. I have to execute this script from another application which needs those last two lines.

Comment: then it simply is: ```return $Avail_Bytes.'Avail Bytes'``` , so you only get the value back without property name